# Check to see if a column value is contained by another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the table called Host in SQL as follows.

```
**FirstName**   **LastName**
 Krishna          Krishna Murthy
 Jithendra        Jithendra Reddy
 Varun            Varun Kumar
 Mahendra         Varma
```

if firstname column is a part of LastName column I need to create one more column with values yes/No.
Output should as follows

```
**FirstName**   **LastName**        **Subset**
 Krishna          Krishna Murthy      Yes
 Jithendra        Jithendra Reddy     Yes
 Varun            Varun Kumar         Yes
 Mahendra         Varma               No
```

any ideas?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Please feel free to tag with the database you are actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, 
    CASE WHEN LastName LIKE '%' + FirstName + '%' 
    THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' 
    END AS Flag
FROM host
```

to get the results you are looking for.

If you just want to search for cases where the forename is repeated, you might want to adjust the case to `LastName LIKE FirstName + ' %'` to ensure that it only matches where there are at least two words, and the first is in FirstName, e.g.

```
**FirstName**   **LastName**        **Subset**
Bob             Bobbins             No
SingleName      SingleName          No
AAA             BBB AAA             No
```

Comment: Thank you so much......Richard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` for this.  In standard SQL, this would look like:

```
select h.*,
       (case when h.lastname like concat('%', h.firstname, '%')
             then 'yes' else 'no'
        end) as flag
from host h;
```

Note that most databases support operators for string concatenation, such as `||` or `+`.

Comment: i am getting an error like Concat is not built in function. i am using sql2008

Comment: @krishna . . . Then you should use the appropriate method for concatenation in your database.  When I answered the question, it had no database tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add column to your table. Fill in existing records using the `UPDATE` statement below, case insensitive.

```
UPDATE host
SET subset = CASE WHEN instr(lower(surname), lower(forename)) > 0 THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END
/
```